For Dart/Flutter projects, can `/lib/foo/src` be used for internal libraries or only the top level `/lib/src`?
For Dart/Flutter projects, there are given guidelines for how to implement internal implementation details, which are typically put into the /lib/src directory. However, can /lib/foo/src be used for internal implementation details for the foo library specifically or do all internal implementation details have to start at the top level /lib/src?

You could, in principle, organize private Dart or Flutter packages however you see fit.
However, for packages that are going to be published it is best to follow the guidelines. The main advantage is that the analyzer will generate the  warning: Import of a library in the 'lib/src' directory of another package if a user of your package depends on a file located in a sub-folder of lib/src:
This warning will not be generated if I depend for example on:
/lib/foo/src/foo_impl.dart.
